# SQL Server 2012 Import Wizard, Oracle view char columns mapped as an <unknown type>, cannot proceed

Tags: sql-server, oracle11g, char, mapping, etl

I am attempting to convert data from an Oracle 11g db to `Sql Server 2012` using `Sql Server Import` and `Export Wizard`. I structured my data in a view that closely resembles how it should look in my `Sql Server` db. 
The view creates 4 char(n) columns, and seems fine.

```
PROGRAM_CODE            4   CHAR (4 Byte)   Y
FEDERAL_PROJECT_NUMBER  5   CHAR (8 Byte)   Y
RECIPIENT_CODE          6   CHAR (2 Byte)   Y
DEMO_ID                 13  CHAR (5 Byte)   Y
```

When I attempt to import the view's data using the `Sql Server` Import wizard, the mapping of each of those columns comes through as .

```
Source                   Destination        Type        
PROGRAM_CODE            PROGRAM_CODE     <unknown type>
etc...
```

I even have other columns that are nvarchar which map with no problem.
I tried switching the columns' type to `varchar`, `nvarchar`, `char`, `nchar`, `sql_variant`, `text` and `ntext`...none of which allowed me to proceed.

Found 4 unknown column type conversion(s)
The package will not be run.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Since I was using a select from query to select the view, I explicitly had to call out each column, and cast the trouble columns to Varchars.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that :
in oracle there are 2 types of char/varchar : byte and char
you can set a column :
columnName varchar(10 byte) or columnName varchar(10 char)

in sql server you cannot do it so you need to delete the key word byte/char

i hope i wrote it clearly
:)